# How did Bowler get there in The Physics of the Dead?

Tags: the-physics-of-the-dead, luke-smitherd

In [*The Physics of the Dead* by Luke Smitherd](http://lukesmitherd.com/books/the-physics-of-the-dead/), when Hart is discovering the 'exit', the beast is happily dismembering Bowler.

Then we see that Hart is talking to Bowler and we discover that Bowler's broken body is next to the exit. Earlier on, the beast stated that he wasn't going to prevent Hart leaving but he did have a plan to mess with him. We can assume that Bowler couldn't get to the exit on his own so that leaves Hart or the beast as his means of transport.

So, did the beast take Bowler to the exit - was this his plan (which backfired big time) to mess with Hart?

Comment: The current consensus is to not include spoilers in the title, but at the same time, to not use spoiler markdown in the body of the text. See https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34/111

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hart, after receiving his vision of the dying man's life and realising how much he owed Bowler, ran to find Bowler's (or in this case Bowler's broken form.) It was Hart carried brought Bowler to the exit so that Bowler could leave.

As for the Beast's plan, it was simply to torment Hart once Bowler was no longer around to be a support mechanism, and to always let Hart - as Hart now knew how to get out - think he was going to escape and then always prevent him doing so at the last minute, in order to screw with him in the worst way possible (The Beast says all this to Bowler.)

P.S. but put a spoiler warning in that title! ;-)

Comment: Hi Luke, welcome to the site. We unfortunately don't have a way of verifying that you are who you say you are. I am therefore going to pretend that this answer came from a normal user of the site. Answers need to be supported by evidence. However, if you add a quote from the passage "The Beast says all this to Bowler", then as far as I am concerned this answer will be sufficiently supported by evidence.

Comment: [Confirmed](https://twitter.com/LukeSmitherd/status/844227708900986881?p=v) that this actually is the author.